# how to bind isenabled property to entry in MVVM when I click on submit button in xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, c#-4.0, cross-platform, mvvmcross, isenabled

I am facing an issue when I submit my form in xamarin form using mvvm architecture my form UI is still able and user can interact while fetching the data from server. I want to disable my UI elements when my submit button is running to fetch the data from server. Actually, I want to bind isEnabled property in my viewmodel. But I do not know how to set it to bool value from my view model and then bind it to the UI elements. What i need to add in my set function so that when someone click on submit button my UI elements will be inactive and user can not edit till the response comes from server.
what to do please assist. Here is my code.

> Blockquote

```
            <StackLayout>
            <Entry x:Name="entryFullName" 
                   Text="{Binding FullName}" 
                   Placeholder="Full Name" 
                   IsEnabled="{Binding block}"
                   />
            
            <Picker x:Name="pickerGender"
                    Title="Gender"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding Genders}"
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedGender}"
                    IsEnabled="{Binding gender}"
                    />
                 </StackLayout>
                 <StackLayout>
            <Button x:Name="btnSubmit"
                    Command="{Binding SubmitCommand}"
                    Text="Submit"
                    />
        </StackLayout>
        <ActivityIndicator IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" />
```

here is my code for my viewmodel submit button function

> Blockquote

```
             private string _Block;

             public string Block
           {
        get { return _Block }
        set { _Block = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
           }
             
     private void OnSubmit()

    {

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FullName))
        {
            this.ErrorOccurred?.Invoke(this, "Please enter full name");
            return;
        }
           Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await this.SaveProfile();
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

first, bind all of your `IsEnabled` properties to the same VM property

```
<Entry x:Name="entryFullName" IsEnabled="{Binding NotBusy}" ... />
<Picker x:Name="pickerGender" IsEnabled="{Binding NotBusy}" ... />
...
<Button x:Name="btnSubmit" IsEnabled="{Binding NotBusy}" ... />
```

then in your MV create a bool property

```
private bool _NotBusy = true;

public bool NotBusy
{
   get { return _NotBusy }
   set { _NotBusy = value; OnPropertyChanged(); }
}
```

finally, when saving set the property

```
private void OnSubmit()
{

   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(this.FullName))
   {
      this.ErrorOccurred?.Invoke(this, "Please enter full name");
      return;
   }
   
   NotBusy = false;
   Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(async () => await this.SaveProfile();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can add a property IsNotSubmitting,

```
private bool _isNotSubmitting = true;
public bool IsNotSubmitting {
    get => _isNotSubmitting ;
    set {
        _isNotSubmitting  = value;
        OnPropertyChanged();
    }
}
```

binding in Xaml:

```
 <Entry x:Name="entryFullName"
    Text="{Binding FullName}" 
    Placeholder="Full Name" 
    IsEnabled="{Binding IsNotSubmitting}"  />
```

now you can set "IsNotSubmitting=false" in the beginning of method SubmitCommand, and you can set "IsNotSubmitting=true" when the commiting is finished